# Can a Sony 700 cover be repaired?

Tags: ebook-readers, sony

I use a Sony PRS-700 ereader while traveling (prefer old fashioned books). But after my last trip I noticed that the cover I bought along with the reader no longer holds it. The gray "clam" at the top that fits in the small hole near the spine of the 700 is bent. I have not been able to get it back and I am afraid to break it off completely. Anyone have experience with this? Is there some place I can buy the cover 2nd hand?

Answer (score 7):

Before bending, warm the "clam" with an electric paint stripper (maybe a hairdryer is enough). I used a heat focusing cone for the stripper. Apply short shots from a short distance until the plastic is warm and stays in shape when moved. Keep in place until cooled. I did this more than one year ago and it still works.

Be very careful with bending when inserting PRS-700 back in. Do not overstretch the plastic again. Also, use tools to prevent burning your fingers.

Mine was broken at top, so not much strain on the plastic while reading.

Answer (score 5):

I broke off the bracket/hinge from my cover while trying to bend it back (not having heated it first as suggested in the other answer, so try that first). After that I completely removed the  plastic grey strip.

The strip is connected at 4 points to the inside of the spine of the cover, and was glued in the middle. You can cut through the connection points with a wire-cutter; work from the outside by lifting the (remains of) the bracket to make space for the cutter. After that use a thin cutter-knife to separate the plastic from the rest of the cover.

I used two pieces of 3.5" velcro sticky back tape (hook & loop) to attach the reader to the right inner side of the cover. Make sure the velcro doesn't cover the reset hole (being able to reset is the reason to use velcro and not something more permanent). I must say the result handles better than with the backside of the cover non-attached.

[image]